# EWS - Create a message with extended property return internal server error

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, exchangewebservices

I want to try to create a message with a mime content. and I add extended property tag so the message not flagged as a draft.
This the example xml request

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1"/>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
            <SavedItemFolderId>
                <t:FolderId Id="AAMkAGE1YTU3MjkyLWFmMjItNGYyZC05Y2ZiLTIwMWY4MjJhMTVlNAA`enter code here`uAAAAAAChtMCk52J3RLzcG5WcyzUkAQCsm0+9jDPcQakVSrf3fxOXAAAAAAEMAAA="/>
            </SavedItemFolderId>
            <Items>
                <t:Message>
                    <t:MimeContent>
                    #-- Mime content goes here --#
                    </t:MimeContent>
                    <t:ExtendedProperty>
                        <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="3591" PropertyType="Integer">
                            <t:Value>1</t:Value>
                        </t:ExtendedFieldURI>
                    </t:ExtendedProperty>
                </t:Message>
            </Items>
        </CreateItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

after I submit, I got the internal server error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">*
        </Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                a:ErrorInternalServerError
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
                An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.    
            </faultstring>
            <detail>
                <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">
                    ErrorInternalServerError
                </e:ResponseCode>
                <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">
                    An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
                </e:Message>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

When I try to remove the extended property tag it works fine. but the message flagged as a draft.

Please advice me how to send the xml request properly.